# validation failing yet its still running execute on struts2

Tags: struts2

im doing a modification on an existing app.  my problem is even tho the validation fails for the form submit, its still executing the execute method.

my struts file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<!-- <include file="com/paritysys/util/struts.xml" /> -->

<constant name="struts.url.includeParams" value="none" />
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="html,action" />

<package name="public" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="websiteOnline"
            class="parity.action.website.OnlineInterceptor" />
        <interceptor name="websiteLogin"
            class="parity.action.website.LoginInterceptor" />

        <interceptor-stack name="appStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <!-- <interceptor-ref name="paritySessionStack"/> -->
            <interceptor-ref name="websiteOnline" />
            <interceptor-ref name="websiteLogin" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="appStack" />

    <global-results>
        <result name="login" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">index</param>
        </result>
        <result name="exception" type="freemarker">/public/error.html.ftl</result>
        <result name="error" type="freemarker">/public/error.html.ftl</result>
        <result type="freemarker" name="maintenance">/public/maintenance.html
        </result>
        <result type="freemarker" name="pre-offline">/public/pre-offline.html
        </result>
        <result type="freemarker" name="post-offline">/public/post-offline.html
        </result>
    </global-results>

    <action name="index" class="parity.action.website.LoginAction">
        <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/index.html.ftl</result>
    </action>

    <action name="login" class="parity.action.website.SubmitLoginAction">
        <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/questionnaire.html.ftl
        </result>
        <result type="freemarker" name="input">/public/index.html.ftl</result>
    </action>

    <action name="submit" class="parity.action.website.SubmitQuestionnaireAction">
        <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/thanks.html.ftl
        </result>
        <result type="freemarker" name="input">/public/questionnaire.html.ftl
        </result>
    </action>

    <action name="whereIsMyId" class="parity.action.website.LoginAction">
        <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/whereIsMyId.html.ftl
        </result>
    </action>

    <action name="loadCollegeFinder" class="parity.action.website.LoadCollegeFinderAction">
        <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/college_finder.html.ftl
        </result>
    </action>

    <action name="findCollege" class="parity.action.website.FindCollegeAction">
        <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/college_finder.html.ftl
        </result>
        <result type="freemarker" name="input">/public/college_finder.html.ftl
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

my action class code

```
public void validate() {
        logger.debug("validate fired");
Bla bla bla
addFieldError("username","error");

        if (hasFieldErrors()) {
            logger.debug("Field errors is true");
        }
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("execute firing");

        return result;
    }
```

any ideas why this would happen?  for some reason even tho the login.action is failing, its still sending down the success return and moving forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You interceptor stack doesn't include the "workflow" interceptor stack, which is what determines what to do on a validation failure.

For that matter, it doesn't include the "params" interceptor, which is how parameters are set on the action, so it will never work anyway. You can't just arbitrarily remove interceptors--it's where S2 gets the bulk of its functionality. [See the interceptor docs.](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/interceptors.html)

Also, you can set a default result type--you may want to do that if most everything is a FreeMarker result rather than type it over and over.