# Struts2 freemarker not submitting form fields

Tags: struts2, freemarker

this is so basic i can't believe ive spent a full day on it already.

ok, here's my freemarker page

```
    bla bla bla
<form name="message" action="[@s.url action="login"/]" onsubmit="return detectJavaScript();" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>To begin, type your Graduation Report ID and password</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                [@requiredInstruction /]
                <label for="username" accesskey="U">
                    [@requiredField /] <strong>Graduation Report ID:</strong>
                </label>
                <input id="username" name="username" size="10" tabindex="1" type="text" value="${username!''}"
                    [@errorStyle show=(fieldErrors?exists && fieldErrors["username"]?exists)/] />
                [@showFieldError field="username" /]
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="password" accesskey="P">
                    [@requiredField /] <strong>Password:</strong>
                </label>
                <input id="password" name="password" size="10" tabindex="2" type="password" value="${password!''}" 
                    [@errorStyle show=(fieldErrors?exists && fieldErrors["password"]?exists)/] />
                [@showFieldError field="password" /]
            </li>
bla bla bla
```

and my action class

```
public class SubmitLoginAction {
    public String username;
    public String password;


    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SubmitLoginAction.class);

    public void validate() {
        logger.debug("validate fired");

        logger.debug("username returned: " + username);
        logger.debug("password returned: " + password);
```

and my struts file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <!-- <include file="com/paritysys/util/struts.xml" /> -->

    <constant name="struts.url.includeParams" value="none" />
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="html,action" />

    <package name="public" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="websiteOnline"
                class="parity.action.website.OnlineInterceptor" />
            <interceptor name="websiteLogin"
                class="parity.action.website.LoginInterceptor" />

            <interceptor-stack name="appStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="workflow"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
                <!-- <interceptor-ref name="paritySessionStack"/> -->
                <interceptor-ref name="websiteOnline" />
                <interceptor-ref name="websiteLogin" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="appStack" />

        <global-results>
            <result name="login" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">index</param>
            </result>
            <result name="exception" type="freemarker">/public/error.html.ftl</result>
            <result name="error" type="freemarker">/public/error.html.ftl</result>
            <result type="freemarker" name="maintenance">/public/maintenance.html
            </result>
            <result type="freemarker" name="pre-offline">/public/pre-offline.html
            </result>
            <result type="freemarker" name="post-offline">/public/post-offline.html
            </result>
        </global-results>

        <action name="index" class="parity.action.website.LoginAction">
            <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/index.html.ftl</result>
        </action>

        <action name="login" class="parity.action.website.SubmitLoginAction">
            <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/questionnaire.html.ftl
            </result>
            <result type="freemarker" name="input">/public/index.html.ftl</result>
        </action>

        <action name="submit" class="parity.action.website.SubmitQuestionnaireAction">
            <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/thanks.html.ftl
            </result>
            <result type="freemarker" name="input">/public/questionnaire.html.ftl
            </result>
        </action>

        <action name="whereIsMyId" class="parity.action.website.LoginAction">
            <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/whereIsMyId.html.ftl
            </result>
        </action>

        <action name="loadCollegeFinder" class="parity.action.website.LoadCollegeFinderAction">
            <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/college_finder.html.ftl
            </result>
        </action>

        <action name="findCollege" class="parity.action.website.FindCollegeAction">
            <result type="freemarker" name="success">/public/college_finder.html.ftl
            </result>
            <result type="freemarker" name="input">/public/college_finder.html.ftl
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

no matter what i do it keeps returning null for the user and pass.  ive tried with getters and setters, without, nothing seems to work.

i thought this was an out of the box thing with struts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, but you've removed it from the box and shuffled its bits around.

You've removed the "params" interceptor from the default interceptor stack. The "params" interceptor is what sets the parameters on the action. I mentioned that in [my answer to your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013941/validation-failing-yet-its-still-running-execute-on-struts2/8013977#8013977).

(Along with eliminating the need to keep typing "freemarker".)

(On a side note, I really don't recommend public properties, although it will work, depending on your version of Struts--IIRC one of the OGNL version bumps changed that.)

Comment: yea, i reread that post and realized what i did.  i restructured the interceptors and added strutsdefault to it.  that brought pieces i wasn't even aware were not working (or existed) back online.  quite interesting actually.  this is a modification to an existing project so i have to follow the same design style as the previous vendor.  can't wait till i can get rid of this thing and overhaul the backend.

Comment: @scphantm Yep, a lot (most) functionality is wrapped up in the interceptors--I learned early to check them first to make sure I'm doing what I thought I was :/